# Rendimiento en Java de abstract vs interface

Tags: java

En términos de rendimiento, en cuanto a velocidad de ejecución se refiere, que es más rápido, ejecutar un método usando una clase abstract ó interface.

Comment: El tiempo que requiere un método para completar una tarea no es dependiente del *polimorfismo*.

Comment: Teóricamente, no debe tomarle tiempo ya que el código de la implementación de ambas se pre-carga al importar las clases. Quizá al ejecutarse el código desde una clase abstracta tome mas tiempo debido a las validaciones de jerarquías de clases y otros temas de los que la maquina virtual se encarga, pero técnicamente son despreciables (menores a 1 ms, quizá hablamos de ns) y no debieses darle mayor importancia, ya que son de muy bajo nivel, prácticamente tendrías que meterte a ver el código de la jvm para saber como se implementan y cargan las clases desde el sistema operativo.

Comment: De todas formas lee [Loading, Linking, and Initializing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) para entender como jvm carga las clases y resuelve las dependencias. [Java vm specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html)

Answer (score 7):

Abstract o Interface no está relacionado con desempeño, sino a abstracción o estructura.

Comment: @Alan en realidad esta es una respuesta aceptable, concreta y sólida para lo que es Java.

Answer (score 3):

No se si entiendo bien la pregunta pero q yo sepa no se puede ejecutar ningún método de una interfaz sino desde la clase que la implementa, por tanto el rendimiento seria igual porque en ambos estarías ejecutando el método de una clase.

Comment: jajaj bien jugado !! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generalmente un método en Java ejecuta el código que contiene, nada más, nada menos. Eso no depende del polimorfismo. Por ejemplo:

```
public  class A() {
    public void metodoUno(){
        // implementacion
    }

    public void metodoDos(){
        // implementacion
    }
}

public interface I() {
    public void metodoTres();
}

public class B extends A implements I{
    @Override
    public metodoTres(){
        // implementacion
    }
}
```

Es equivalente en aspectos de rendimiento a

```
public abstract class A() {
    public void metodoUno(){
        // implementacion
    }

    public void metodoDos(){
        // implementacion
    }

    public abstract void metodoTres();

}

public class B extends A
    @Override
    public metodoTres(){
        // implementacion
    }
}
```

mientras el código de la implementación es equivalente.

- No hay diferencia entre un método abstracto implementado en una subclase y un método implementado basado en una interfaz
- Una clase abstracta se puede interpretar como una clase que implementa parcialmente una interfaz y sirve como superclase y interfaz en uno

Si durante del desarrollo se empieza de hacer @Override a métodos implementados en la superclase, más que nada si se llama a `super` del mismo método en el @Override, obviamente si existe un costo en rendimiento que no es visible desde solamente mirar el código de la subclase.

También durante la creación de objetos hay que tomar en cuenta que es necesario de mientras se insta una clase, hay que ejecutar los constructores de las superclases, para garantizar una construcción completa y correcta de la clase en toda su funcionalidad, y construir clases **si** es costoso.

Más que consideraciones de rendimiento, la elección entre clase abstracta o interfaz deberia basarse en la pregunta si hay código que las clases finales con alta probabilidad van a tener en común, para evitar repeticiónes y mejorar la mantenibilidad.